# How to remove Codota Plugin from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

I want to remove Codota plugin from the android studio, But on the plugin page, there is no option for uninstall, there is only update option.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: may i know why u want to remove codota plugin i found it very useful

Comment: It was creating a problem in the android studio. I had tried multiple things that time but did not worked, after removing this worked perfectly.

Comment: now it improved lot .. u check once

Comment: Ok will check soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File>Setting>Plugins
```

For disable plugin.

> Unselect `Checbox` ahead **`Codota`** Then press `apply`.

For uninstall

> Click on `Codota` inside plugin, at right side you will see `Uninstall` button.

**If you don't see Uninstall button, then Restart Android Studio, recent installed plugin requires restart first.**

[image]

Comment: @KheKhemraj Thanks it works. Uncheck works, but there is no option for uninstall

Comment: No problem, if you disable plugin then plugin will not acquire any memory.